# how to send a email with multiple variables sent

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP Pear - adding variables to $body message (resolved)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7528530/php-pear-adding-variables-to-body-message-resolved)

I have a jQuery page with a basic form and i stored each entered information into a specific variable which then uses Ajax but when I submit the form

It works but it sends only one variable in the message rather then multiple variables which I need..

The variables are correctly linked up because I can have the function having either one of those variables and it displays it but when I try send multiple it only shows one.

I apologize if its not clear enough its quite hard to explain, I thought using `+`'s would work but it did not.

```
<?php

$telephone = $_POST['telephone'];
$address = $_POST['address'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$feedback = $_POST['feedback'];

mail($email,"hello" ,$feedback+$address+$telephone);

?>
```

Comment: Put all variables into an array and send them together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The plus `+` operator is for numeric values.

```
$feedback+$address+$telephone
```

So your addition will lead to a `0`.

Use the [string concatenation operator `.`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6484968/what-does-a-dot-do-in-php) or just a string with variables in it:

```
"  $feedback $address $telephone  "
```

See also:

- [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)
- http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Answer (score 3):

its like

```
 mail(to,subject,message,headers,parameters)
```

try

```
$message="$feedback.$address.$telephone";
mail($email,"hello" ,$message);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code looks fine. You might have the Java Style of string concatenation (check http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)
 Try to put all the string variables in one $message string and you are good to go.

```
<?php

$telephone = $_POST['telephone'];
$address = $_POST['address'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$feedback = $_POST['feedback'];
$message="$feedback.$address.$telephone";
mail($email,"hello" ,$message);

?>
```

Since the mail function in php returns boolean, you can also do some check:

```
<?php
if (!mail($email,"hello" ,$message)){
//LOG ERROR 
//OR output
echo "Could not send mail, try checking php logs or enable logs via ini_set('display_errors',1)"
}
```

Comment: This Worked 100% Perfectly !!